# Shopify authentication SSO

Tags: google-oauth, shopify, single-sign-on

I am new to Shopify and I am trying to connect my customers to my store with SSO (Google).
I can't find any reference of how should I sign up as a user after I got a response from Google API (with token and email).

I don't want to use apps/plugins and I want to implement it by myself.
Does anyone have experience with SSO to Shopify and can explain how os the flow?